# Procedure for deleting records referenced from other tables in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, cursor, plpgsql, sql-delete

I am trying to create a Stored Procedure in Postgresql that allow me to delete foreign keys from other tables without using the DELETE CASCADE when creating tables but gives me an error that one id is still referenced in other table. This is the code i have tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_delete_restaurante_msg
                           ( _id_restaurante   integer, 
                             _id_local         integer, 
                             _nome_restaurante varchar(100), 
                             INOUT _msg        varchar(100), 
                             INOUT _msg1       varchar(100) )
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE

    loc_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT local.id_local FROM local WHERE local.id_local = _id_local FOR UPDATE;
    ementa_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT ementa.id_restaurante FROM ementa WHERE ementa.id_restaurante = _id_restaurante FOR UPDATE;
    func_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT funcionario.id_restaurante FROM funcionario WHERE funcionario.id_restaurante = _id_restaurante FOR UPDATE;
    apont_loc RECORD;
    apont_em RECORD;
    apont_func RECORD;

BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(SELECT l.id_local, rest.id_restaurante FROM local l JOIN restaurante rest ON l.id_local = rest.id_local WHERE rest.id_restaurante = _id_restaurante AND
              l.id_local = _id_local) THEN
        DELETE FROM restaurante WHERE restaurante.id_restaurante = _id_restaurante;
        COMMIT;
    ELSE
        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM local WHERE local.id_local = _id_local) > 0 THEN
        OPEN loc_cursor;
        LOOP
            FETCH NEXT FROM loc_cursor INTO apont_loc;
            EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
            IF apont_loc.id_local = _id_local THEN
                DELETE FROM local WHERE CURRENT OF loc_cursor;
                COMMIT;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE loc_cursor;
        COMMIT;
        ELSIF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ementa WHERE ementa.id_restaurante = _id_restaurante) > 0 THEN
            OPEN ementa_cursor;
            LOOP
                FETCH NEXT FROM ementa_cursor INTO apont_em;
                EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
                IF apont_em.id_restaurante = _id_restaurante THEN
                    DELETE FROM ementa WHERE CURRENT OF ementa_cursor;
                    COMMIT;
                END IF;
            END LOOP;
            CLOSE ementa_cursor;
            COMMIT;
        ELSIF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM funcionario WHERE funcionario.id_restaurante = _id_restaurante) > 0 THEN
            OPEN func_cursor;
            LOOP
                FETCH NEXT FROM func_cursor INTO apont_func;
                EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
                IF apont_func.id_restaurante = _id_restaurante THEN
                    DELETE FROM funcionario WHERE CURRENT OF func_cursor;
                    COMMIT;
                END IF;
                END LOOP;
                CLOSE func_cursor;
        ELSE
            RAISE NOTICE 'Nao existe mais tabelas ligadas';
        END IF;
    END IF;
    IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM restaurante WHERE restaurante.id_restaurante = _id_restaurante) = 0 THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION '%', _msg;
        ROLLBACK;
    END IF;
    IF _nome_restaurante IS NULL OR _nome_restaurante = '' THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION '%', _msg1;
        ROLLBACK;
    END IF;
END;
$$
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use ON DELETE CASCADE?

Comment: A cursor is almost always the worst choice. A single `DELETE ... WHERE ..` statement is most probably a lot more efficient. And running a `SELECT count()` before the delete is completely useless and inefficient.

Comment: As far as I can tell you can simplify your procedure to this: https://pastebin.com/XLevugmj - maybe it needs nested sub-select but as you didn't show us the dependencies between the tables it's really hard to decipher that from the needlessly over-complicated procedure you have

Comment: i am gonna use this procedure in django to connect to my database. I should have put ON DELETE CASCADE before creating tables but i didn't do it and i need to do something different and i tried to use cursors but it seems i had some problems. I will see that pastebin to see if it helps :)

Comment: this is my pastebin for the table dependencies if you guys want to check it out https://pastebin.com/S1MTuBWK